# Discord.js | profile info from user id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my discord.js bot to be able to give info on a user with the id provided but I'm can't get that to work. I tried with the guild#fetchUser(id) but it just returns undefined. And even if it worked, I would need the user, to the member classes, for example, to be able to give basic info (created at...) of a user even outside the guild.
Here's my code:

```
if(!args[0]){
    const profileEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    //rest of the code
    message.channel.send(profileEmbed);
}else{
  let taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!taggedUser){
      taggedUser = args[0];
    }
  const profileEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(taggedUser.tag, taggedUser.displayAvatarURL())
    //rest of the code
    message.channel.send(profileEmbed);
}
```

how do I like fin the username and all the user properties from an id?
thanks :)

**UPDATE**
I found out that I can use taggedUser = bot.users.fetch(args[0]); to get the user properties, but it doesn't display properties such as the creation date, how would I find that?

```
client#users.fetch(id)
```

returns

```
Promise {
  User {
    id: 'bla bla bla',
    bot: false,
    username: 'bla bla bla',
    discriminator: 'bla bla bla',
    avatar: 'bla bla bla',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  }
}
```

**how do I find like the creation date and creation Time?**

Comment: You want user tag to show in embed?

Comment: You should to tell verison of discord.js

Comment: Giving us code to "fix" isn't very useful. Please tell us what you have tried, what you want the exact result to be (not just "info about user", that is very vague) and any possible logs / results that may help us understand your problem.

Comment: @TCoded  updated it!

Comment: You will either need to convert `User` into a `Member` or fetch the member by `<Guild>.members.fetch`. If you are not inside of a guild of the user, you will not be able to get the info.

Comment: @Karizma I thought i would be able to get that info because I saw some bots (such as logibot) being able to get info from users that have never been inside of one of their guilds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. `const` is a constant Variable, this means it values cannot be changed by overwriting it. For this you need to use `var` or `let`
You can make your Code more simple by adding this.
`const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author`

What would result in this Code:

```js
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat)
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/')
}
const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author //if mention does not exists message.author will be used
if(taggedUser){
    const profileEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(taggedUser.tag, taggedUser.displayAvatarURL())
    //rest of the code
    message.channel.send(profileEmbed);
}
```

Hope this Helped solving your Issue!

EDIT: `taggedUser.createdAt();`

Comment: For example `const x = 1`, but then you cant override it by doing `const x = 2`. This will throw you an Error. Since i dont override my taggedUser Variable i use `const`. What you can do with `let` or `var` is for example `var x = 1 ` but if you want to override it you can do `var x = 1` . The same applies with `let` @froggit

Comment: @froggit The user needs to be cached within your Bot. Make sure to set my Question as Solution (CHECKMARk below my Downvote)

Comment: The user doesn't need to be cached, he can use `<Client>.users.fetch()`, the user does need to be in a guild as the bot though.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out! to know the creation date of an user not in the guild, you can just guess the age based on the id! [here's the article from discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes)